# In my iphone application I want to provide a functionality to import Facebook,gmail contacts

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I think my question it self is self explanatory. though, I'm repeating my self, How can I Implement the functionality to import facebook and gmail contacts to my iphone application. 
please give me your valuable suggestions.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [facebook api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/) and [google contacts api](http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/). It takes minimal effort to find these yourself.

Comment: Actually I have already tried this to integrate with my app. But when I was trying to do so, It was asking my App ID, and I haven't submit my app yet so How am I suppose to get it. If I'm doing something wrong please let me know. thanks for your help.

Comment: You should register in the iOS Developer Program to get a developer ID. Than you can get also App IDs. It seems to me it costs $100/year. https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/

Answer (score 0):

For Facebook, try the Facebook Graph API [Link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/). It will return JSON-Files. Google offers also a API for Google Contacts [Link](http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/3.0/developers_guide.html)